# a cuda kernel function with a big struct variable gives wrong result

Tags: c++, struct, cuda

I have a cuda kernel function to swap elements in a struct array, but when the struct element is big enough, for example, takes up more than 120 byte, the swap is wrong. Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h> 

using namespace std;

const int f_num = 30;
const int d_num = 15;

struct S
{
    int constID;
    float f[f_num];
    //double d[d_num];
};

__global__ void
cudaSwap(S *s, int n)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    S temp;
    if(tid < n)
    {
        temp = s[tid];
        s[tid] = s[tid + n];
        s[tid +n] = temp;
    }
}
int main()
{
    cout << "sizeof float is " << sizeof(float) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof double is " << sizeof(double) << endl;

    S *h_s = new S[20];
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        h_s[i].constID = i;
        for(int j = 0; j < f_num; ++j)
        {
            h_s[i].f[j] = (float)i + (float)j/100;
            //h_s[i].d[j] = (double)i + (double)j/100;
        }
    }

    cout << "original h_s:" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        cout << h_s[i].constID << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    S *d_s;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_s, sizeof(S) * 20);
    cudaMemset(d_s, 0, sizeof(S) * 20);
    cudaMemcpy(d_s, h_s, sizeof(S) * 20, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaSwap<<<1,20>>>(d_s, 5);

    cudaMemcpy(h_s, d_s, sizeof(S) * 20, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cout << "swaped h_s:" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        cout << h_s[i].constID << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    delete [] h_s;
    cudaFree(d_s);

    return 0;
}
```

When the struct consists of less than 30 float elements or 15 double elements, the result is 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 10 11 ..., but when the struct element is bigger, the result is 5 6 7 8 9 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ..., which means that `s[tid +n] = temp;` has no effect. I'm new in cuda, could anyone tell me the reason of the problem and how to solve the problem? Maybe it has something to do with register? I'm not sure...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: When I set `f_num = 31` I am able to reproduce the problem reported with CUDA 7.5 and CUDA 8.0.61.  I am unable to reproduce the problem with CUDA 9.0.67 (CUDA 9 EA, not widely or publicly available yet).  I think there may be an underlying bug here in CUDA that you have tripped on (but I haven't studied it carefully).  It seems to be fixed in the upcoming CUDA 9 release.  I've looked over your code carefully and I don't think it has any coding defects in it.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this at all with CUDA 8.0.60, GeForce 970m (driver 21.21.13.7651), Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis how exactly are you compiling?  In particular, are you compiling with an arch switch that matches the architecture of your 970m?

Comment: @RobertCrovella with `-gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\"`

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis is it a 32-bit or is it a 64-bit project?  is it debug or release?  According to my testing, the problem does not manifest in debug mode (`-G`) on cuda 7.5/8.0

Comment: @RobertCrovella ok, release did the trick.

Comment: I can confirm as well, anyone submit a bug report to nvidia yet?

Looking at the disassembly, the entire struct assignment is being done with registers one value at a time, and there's no ptx associated with s[tid +n] = temp;.

Comment: It is true that the program compiled under debug mode gives the correct result, and the release one gives the wrong result. My device is K80, CUDA 7.5, 64-bit, arch=compute_30, code=sm_30. Seems that it's not a problem that can be easily solved?

Comment: I think if you file a bug with NVIDIA, the response will be that you should use CUDA 9 when it becomes available.  (But feel free to file a bug.)  As far as workarounds, I'm sure there are many.  For example, if you replace the last line in your kernel: `s[tid +n] = temp;` with a similar `memcpy` call: `memcpy(s+tid+n, &temp, sizeof(S));` it seems to fix the issue according to my testing on CUDA 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a compiler bug in CUDA 7.5 and CUDA 8 (it is unaffected by PTX optimization level, according to my tests, so I believe the bug enters in the generation of PTX from CUDA source, not in the compilation of PTX to SASS).

Compiling with the debug switch (`-G`) appears to make the problem disappear, but this has negative implications for performance.

It appears to be fixed in CUDA 9 EA according to my testing, therefore I expect it to be fixed in CUDA 9 when that is publicly available.

One possible simple workaround would be to modify the kernel code as follows:

```
__global__ void
cudaSwap(S *s, int n)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    S temp;
    if(tid < n)
    {
        temp = s[tid];
        s[tid] = s[tid + n];
        memcpy(s+tid+n, &temp, sizeof(S));  // this line is changed
    }
}
```

This appears to resolve the problem for the case presented here, in CUDA 8, according to my testing.

Comment: In CUDA 7.5, this solution also works. Thank you very much!